Did I correctly derive the equation $yy'+(\frac{y'}{y}-\frac{y}{y'})=-\frac{2}{tanx}$ from $sin(y)=y\sin(x)$?
I'm trying to solve a differential equation $siny/y=sin(x)$ to normalize the phase of the spherical bessel functions.
My purpose is to find y=f(x) that satisfies the equation above.
What I want to solve is $yy'+(\frac{y'}{y}-\frac{y}{y'})=-\frac{2}{tanx}$, which was derived by the following process.
To find the $y=f(x)$ that satisfies $siny/y=sin(x)$, the both sides of the equation was differentiated.
$sin(y)=y\sin(x)$ ------- (1)
$y'\cos(y)=y\cos(x)+y'\sin(x)$ ------- (2)
Then, $y'$ was multiplied to equation (1) to eliminate the cos(y) term
$y'\sin(y)=yy'\sin(x)$ ------- (3)
Equation (2) and (3) was squared and added
$(y')^2\cos^2(y)=y^2\cos^2(x)+2yy'\cos(x)\sin(x)+(y')^2\sin^2(x)$ ------- (4)
$(y')^2\sin^2(y)=(yy')^2\sin^2(x)$ ------- (5)
$(y')^2=y^2\cos^2(x)+2yy'\cos(x)\sin(x)+(y')^2\sin^2(x)+(yy')^2\sin^2(x)$ ------- (4) + (5)
This arranged to
$(y')^2(\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x))=y^2\cos^2(x)+2yy'\cos(x)\sin(x)+(y')^2\sin^2(x)+(yy')^2\sin^2(x)$
$y^2\cos^2(x)+2yy'\cos(x)\sin(x)-(y')^2\cos^2(x)+(yy')^2\sin^2(x)=0$ ------- (6)
(6) can be arranged to the following 2 equations by dividing it with $yy'$.
$\frac{y}{y'}\cos^2(x)+\frac{y'}{y}\sin^2(x)=\frac{y'}{y}-2\cos(x)\sin(x)-yy'\sin^2x$ ------- (7)
$\frac{y'}{y}\cos^2(x)+\frac{y}{y'}\sin^2(x)=\frac{y}{y'}+2\cos(x)\sin(x)+yy'\sin^2x$ ------- (8)
Subtracting (7) from (8)
$(\frac{y'}{y}-\frac{y}{y'})(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))=(\frac{y'}{y}-\frac{y}{y'})+4\cos(x)\sin(x)+2yy'\sin^2x$
$(\frac{y'}{y}-\frac{y}{y'})(-2\sin^2(x))=4\cos(x)\sin(x)+2yy'\sin^2x$
$(\frac{y'}{y}-\frac{y}{y'})=-\frac{2}{tanx}-yy'$
$yy'+(\frac{y'}{y}-\frac{y}{y'})=-\frac{2}{tanx}$
And I stucked here.
Am I solved it correctly and is there analytical method that can solve the differential equation?
If not, I'll try numerical method.
Thank you

Check the equation (5). It should be (y')^2  sin^2y=(y')^2  y^2  sin^2x

${\sin y\over y}=x$ is not a differential equation.

It's not clear what you are trying to solve.  $\frac {\sin y}y=x$ isn't a differential equation.  It just gives us $x$ as a function of $y$ or, if you prefer, it implicitly gives us $y$ as a function of $x$.

I'm solving $\frac{\sin(y)}{y}=\sin(x)$. Of course it can implicitly give me the answer, but I'm solving the equation just for fun.

I only read the first part, but in equation (2), are you taking the derivative with respect to x or y on the right side? It seems like you are kind of combining the two in a way that doesn't make much sense to me. It may help to write x as a function of and try to work it out that way.

There is no derivative in that equation.  Also:  In the header you have $\frac {\sin y}y=\sin x$ but in the body of your post you have $\frac {\sin y}y=x$.  This is very unclear.

Can you edit your post for clarity?  As it stands, there is no derivative in that equation, so it is not a differential equation.  It's not clear what you are trying to solve.

Sorry for the ambiguity. I'm suffering from ADHD so the text was unorganized but I coudn't notice. Again, I apologize for my confusing question.
